# Why Javascript sha1 and PHP5 sha1 generate different result for utf-8 string?

Tags: php, javascript, sha1

I have a string which contains some utf-8 characters, like "abc艾", and found that php5 sha1 generate a different code compared with Javascript sha1, could anyone help me this out? Thanks in advance.

phpcode:

```
$str = "abc艾";
$result = sha1($str);
```

result is `5345129746e444693aa1111c5840e4b57236f002`

javascript code:

```
var str = "abc艾"
var result = sha1(str)
```

result is `8a2aa0fed185dcffb922b1c4d67a49105525bd6a`

Comment: `sha1` is not a native Javascript function, is it?

Comment: No, it is not. Sorry to post a incomplete code, actually sha1 in my code is a wrapper for crypto-js, original code is like: var result = CryptoJS.SHA1("abc艾");

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what CryptoJS does, but... strings are very different beasts in JS and PHP. In PHP strings are a byte stream in a certain encoding, JS `String` objects are a *character string* in no particular encoding as far as the accessible API is concerned. So it depends on how `CryptoJS.SHA1()` works in particular and how it gets from a JS `String` object to a byte representation it can make a hash of.

Answer (score 7):

The result you are getting from PHP is correct for the string encoded as GB18030 (`61 62 63 B0 AC`)

The one you're getting from CryptoJS is correct for the string encoded as UTF-8 (`61 62 63 E8 89 BE`).

There is no conflict here. Your PHP source file is saved using the incorrect string encoding, so the result you're getting is not representative.

Please read [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/). In short, what you are dealing with as "艾" is a *Unicode* character, not a "UTF-8 character". There are multiple ways in which it may be represented by different systems, and these different representations have different SHA1 sums.

Comment: Thanks much duskwuff, you answered my question perfectly. After I encode "艾" from GB18030 to utf8, php and javascript generate the same result.